# Qunit tests are not working on visual studio 2012 as they work on browser

Tags: visual-studio-2012, breeze, single-page-application, qunit, chutzpah

I have developed an SPA application using knockout and breeze, I have been using **qunitJS for unit testing which works well on browser for my project**. Recently I have found a plugin "Chutzpah" for VS2012, which can work well for testing qunit, which can check the test cases and respond for the Test though I am using breeze my test cases includes:

1. Creating, Deleting, Modifying entities on client side
2. Save changes on server side using breeze controller to SQLServer

Here the problem is the **breeze test cases fails when I am testing in Chutzpah** because they are not getting client side information like(Metadata/ ControllerMethods) which is called by the browser through the url defined in Breezeconfig. My question is that **how can we perform unit test on breeze on server side** like real unit test cases do. 
**Suggestions for using new plugins or libraries which can actually make me do the unit testing of breeze are welcome**

Here is the snippet for my testing project:

```
 asyncTest("can save nothing", function () {
  expect(1);
  newEm().saveChanges()
      .then(function(saveResult) {
          equal(saveResult.entities.length, 0, 'succeeded in saving nothing');
      })
      .catch(handleFail).finally(start);
});

asyncTest("can save a new Customer entity", function () {
  expect(1);

    // Create and initialize entity to save
    var em = newEm();
    var customer = em.createEntity('Customer', {
        CustomerID: newGuidComb(),
        CompanyName: 'Test1 ' + new Date().toISOString()
    });

    em.saveChanges()
        .then(function (saveResults) {
            ok(!!saveResults.entities[0], ' should have saved new Customer with CustomerID ' +
                customer.getProperty('CustomerID'));
        })
        .catch(handleFail).finally(start);
});

asyncTest("can modify my own Customer entity", function () {
    expect(2);
    var timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
    var em = newEm();

    var customer = em.createEntity('Customer', {
        CustomerID: newGuidComb(),
        CompanyName: "Test2A " + timestamp
    });

    em.saveChanges().then(modifyCustomer).fail(handleSaveFailed).fin(start);

    function modifyCustomer(saveResults) {
        var saved = saveResults.entities[0];
        ok(saved && saved === customer,
            "save of added customer should have succeeded");
        customer.CompanyName("Test2M " + timestamp);
        return em.saveChanges()
        .then(confirmCustomerSaved);
    }

    function confirmCustomerSaved(saveResults) {
        var saved = saveResults.entities[0];
        ok(saved && saved === customer,
            "save of modified customer, '{0}', should have succeeded"
            .format(saved && saved.CompanyName()));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is to set up the tests so that server communication is not required.  [Capture the metadata](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/load-metadata-script) so that you can load it from a script before you run your tests.
[Create mock data](https://pwkad.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/creating-mocks-with-breeze-js/) in Breeze so that you query from the local EntityManager instead of the server.

And, of course, you should separate the business logic of your application (the kind that needs a lot of testing) from the server-communication bits.

Comment: Thanks Steve,We can load metadata and can query using local EntityManager, But what about saving data back to database and retrieving it, how do we do it?? If I got this answer,then my problem is mostly solved.